# Given FrameRate does not match with real FrameRate

Tags: matlab

I am testing my laptop integrated cam, and after writing this simple code, FrameRates doesn't match. It shows that it's 30fps, but after calc I can see it's the half, 15fps. This is the code:

```
vid = videoinput('winvideo',1);
frameRates = set(getselectedsource(vid), 'FrameRate')
vid.FramesPerTrigger = 30;
start(vid); [frames, timeStamp] = getdata(vid);
frameRateCalc = 1/mean(diff(timeStamp))
```

And this is the output

```
>> framerate

frameRates = 

    '30.0000'


frameRateCalc =

   15.2007
```

I have tested with another external cam and seems to work fine, 30 match with 30. Anybody knows why they doesn't match with the integrated cam?

Comment: It's possible that integrated cam does not support higher frame rate. Try to reduce the resolution of the frames sent by the camera (if the feature is supported).

Comment: Shouldn't you call `get(selectedsource(vid), 'FrameRate')` or  `getselectedsource(vid).FrameRate` instead of `set` to obtain the actual frame rate?